# How to sync records instead of download whole Datastore?

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Javascript SDK to access Dropbox Datastore API. I noticed that each time i call *open(Default)Datastore(...)* whole datastore is downloaded to browser using (...)/datastores/get_snapshot endpoint. Is there any way to store records in localStorage and download only those that have changed since some time (simply sync them instead of download them all)? Imagine that user has 10MB in its Datastore. Now - each time when he/she refresh page with my javascript app 10MB will be downloaded? How can implement it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, local caching isn't something that's supported with the current JavaScript SDK. It's a feature we're already considering adding in the future.

Comment: Hmm... It won't be hard for me to implement if you release open source version of SDK. Anyway - thanks for your reply :)

Comment: It's a little trickier than you would think if you want things to work properly when the app is open in multiple browser tabs. But yes, if/when we open-source the JS SDK, a simplified implementation of caching should be fairly easy to build.